# Makefile:273: recipe for target 'install' failed make: *** [install] Error 1 in ubuntu16.04 in Docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04, intel, paho, openvino

I am using Docker container in which i install ubuntu16.04 , i tried to install setup of openvino toolkit so i got the following error when I Install Paho* MQTT C client libraries by following command given in https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/people-counter

```
root@2fe5f8678637:~# cd paho.mqtt.c

root@2fe5f8678637:~/paho.mqtt.c# ls -a

.               CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md  .git           src
..              conanfile.py        .gitignore     test
about.html      CONTRIBUTING.md     .gitreview     test_package
android         .cproject           LICENSE        travis-build.sh
appveyor.yml    debian              Makefile       travis-deploy.sh
build           deploy_rsa.enc      notice.html    travis-env-vars
build.xml       dist                .project       travis-install.sh
 cbuild.bat      doc                 .pydevproject  travis-macos-vars
cmake           edl-v10             README.md      travis-setup-deploy.sh
CMakeLists.txt  epl-v10             .settings      .travis.yml

root@2fe5f8678637:~/paho.mqtt.c# make

mkdir -p build/output/samples
mkdir -p build/output/test
echo OSTYPE is Linux
OSTYPE is Linux

root@2fe5f8678637:~/paho.mqtt.c# sudo make install
mkdir -p build/output/samples
mkdir -p build/output/test
echo OSTYPE is Linux
OSTYPE is Linux
mkdir -p /usr/local/include

install -m 644  build/output/libpaho-mqtt3c.so.1.0 /usr/local/lib
install -m 644  build/output/libpaho-mqtt3cs.so.1.0 /usr/local/lib
install -m 644  build/output/libpaho-mqtt3a.so.1.0 /usr/local/lib
install -m 644  build/output/libpaho-mqtt3as.so.1.0 /usr/local/lib
install  build/output/paho_c_version /usr/local/bin
install  build/output/samples/paho_c_pub /usr/local/bin
install  build/output/samples/paho_c_sub /usr/local/bin
install  build/output/samples/paho_cs_pub /usr/local/bin
install  build/output/samples/paho_cs_sub /usr/local/bin
/sbin/ldconfig /usr/local/lib

ln -s libpaho-mqtt3c.so.1 /usr/local/lib/libpaho-mqtt3c.so

ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/local/lib/libpaho-mqtt3c.so':            File exists
Makefile:273: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Can someone explain what that error means and how to resolve it?

Comment: "I started a bare Ubuntu container and installed software in it" is a dangerous practice: you'll inevitably be forced to delete the container and you'll lose all your work.  I highly recommend reading the official Docker tutorial on [building and running custom images](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/), and then including your Dockerfile in SO questions as a key part of a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ln.1.html):

```
ln [OPTION]... TARGET... DIRECTORY
```

So if your target is `/usr/local/lib/libpaho-mqtt3c.so`, you should use it the other way around, like this:

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/libpaho-mqtt3c.so libpaho-mqtt3c.so.1
```